# ID Attribute: why doesn't it show?

Tags: html, css

Here is my code, so the format with the p#01 id attribute isn't showing at all(I want to assign specific pixel and color to the text for that one element), what is going on? How to fix it

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      p.error {
        color: red; }
      p#01 {
        border:1px solid red;
        padding:10px;
        margin:5px;
        color:blue; }
    </style>
  </head>
```

```
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<p class="error">I am different.</p>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<p class="error">I am different too.</p>
<p id="p01">Tell me what is love</p>
```

Comment: `id="p01"` vs `p#01`. Your CSS selector doesn't match the HTML id.

Comment: use `#p01` instead of `p#01`

Comment: Thanks, it worked!

Comment: Voting to Close as this question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers.

Answer (score 0):

HTML Code:

```
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<p class="error">I am different.</p>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<p class="error">I am different too.</p>
<p id="p01">Tell me what is love</p>
```

CSS Code:

```
p.error {
color: red; }
p#p01 {
border:1px solid red;
padding:10px;
margin:5px;
color:blue; }
```

Demo [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gaus06techian/shwsan15/)

The `id="p01"` used in HTML doesn't match the one used `p#01` in CSS.